# Sql query with sum of sum

Tags: sql

I know that this type of question is answered many times here, but I can't use any answer to solve my problem, so please help. Here is my problem.

```
table 1 

ID1    CustID   Owe

Table 2 

ID2    CustID   Paid
```

I need simple thing, in one sql query I need `sum(TotalOwe - TotalPaid)` as Result where `1.custID=2.custID=@custID` (this is not example of my query, don't correct it, this is just explanation). Or even more simpler, Customer with ID = 112 have TotalOwe of xxx and he is already paid `TotalPaid`, so he now owes `TotalOwe - TotalPaid`.

This looks really simple, I am even little embarrassed for asking, but I really don't have any more time for experimenting. I was close in one moment, but values of `TotalOwe` and `TotalPaid` was doubled, I don't know why but that is another thing.

Comment: This question shows zero effort.

Comment: Your response shows a much greater effort

Comment: At the very least you could have said I tried this SQL statement... instead you said please give me code.

Comment: Ok, you're right about that. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(TotalOwed,0) - COALESCE(TotalPaid,0)
FROM (  SELECT  CustID, 
                SUM(Owe) TotalOwed
        FROM table1 
        GROUP BY CustID) T1
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  CustID,
                    SUM(Paid) TotalPaid
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY CustID) T2
    ON T1.CustID = T2.CustID
WHERE COALESCE(T1.CustID,T2.CustID) = 112
```

Comment: @user2710931 I modified it a little